# Bulk data load jobs missing batches and stuck in Open state

Tags: bulk-api

I am having a problem with Bulk Data Load Jobs where they seem to be submitted without Batches and as such appear to get stuck in Open state until they are manually Aborted.

This is similar to a question raised here,
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AfAqIAK

This is being submitted using the following library,
https://github.com/heroku/salesforce-bulk

Object type: Asset

Operation type: Upsert

Strangely it seems only to affect sandbox instances of Salesforce.